# cannot correctly print labels with glabels app and dymo labelwriter 450

Tags: 22.04

I installed the labelwriter 450 on lubuntu 22.04 LTS, as well as the package glabels.
I can print on the printer but it seems that the glabels or the system does not recognize the label format. The label I want to use is the Dymo 11354 listed as address label.
How can I get it right?

Answer (score 2):

gLabels does indeed have the Dymo 11354 style label in its database.

[image]

After opening the application select `File > New` and in the dialogue box select the `Search All` tab then the `Brand` drop down and navigate to `Dymo` in the list. Select `Any` in the `Page Size` tab and you will be presented with the option to select the *Dymo 11354: Return Address Labels*

Click `Next` in top right hand corner and choose the orientation required (Normal is the default). Select `Review` - click `Apply` (top right) and voila!

I have been using gLabels for many years through many versions of Ubuntu and I have yet to come across any occasion where I have been unable to find a solution by either a label in the database or the ability to create a custom one when required.

[image]

Ubuntu 22.04.4 & gLabels v 3.4.1